# iTerm minimizes when I press ESC

Tags: vim, terminal, iterm2

When I press ESC in VIm insert mode, instead of going back to control mode, my iTerm minimizes and does not go back to control mode, but it stucks in insert mode.

I am using **Vim 7.3** that came with OSX Lion and **iTerm2 Build 1.0.0.20130302**

Any ideas?

EDIT: I also noticed that this is not just a VIm problem but an iTerm2 problem, since it toggles iTerm2 everytime i press ESC no matter in which program I am.

Comment: Well, this is obviously an iTerm problem. A quick look at the preferences, possibly the "Keys" panel, should solve your issue.

Comment: @romainl is there a way to reset iterm settings? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to **Preferences** -> **Keys** and see if you have set up <kbd>Esc</kbd> as a system-wide hotkey for hiding and showing iTerm.

Answer (score 0):

Most terminals will send the Escape code when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>, so you can use that as a workaround if you'd like to keep the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key mapping.